# function or method or function member or method member?

Tags: c#

Several C# authors call C# methods as functions in their books. Probably they are from C or similar programming background. Anything called Function member in C#?  My understanding there is no concept called “function” in C#. Am I miss something here?

Comment: @LaysomeSmith I hope my answer, answers your question. Regards

Answer (score 5):

**Some Background..**

In C# and other languages methods are often referred to as functions. And functions are often referred to as methods. During my understudy for my first year of programming I was taught everything was a function, and on my second year of programming I was then told everything that was a function is now a method (so it goes both ways).

**What is a method or function?**

- A set of statements that perform a specific task
- Code that are be executed many times is a good candidate for functions
- Need only to change common code if necessary
- Functional Decomposition

[image: functional]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/q3ctjp2h.lad.png))</sub>

Credit ([UCOL](https://ucol.ac.nz/), Palmerston North, Edmund Teo, 2008)

**OK.... But what is a function (or method) member?**

> Function members are members that contain executable statements. Function members are always members of types and cannot be members of namespaces. C# defines the following categories of function members:
>
> - Methods
> - Properties
> - Events
> - Indexers
> - User-defined operators
> - Instance constructors
> - Static constructors
> - Destructors

Taken from MSDN *7.4 Function members*, read more [here..](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55979)

**Architecture of a generic method/function.**

[image: Methods]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/hc4hcnw4.rq1.png))</sub>

Credit ([UCOL](https://ucol.ac.nz/), Palmerston North, Aaron Steele, 2009)

Answer (score 1):

I have often seen terms such as functions and methods being used interchangeably. I am sure that there is a formal definition, but in reality, it seems to be kind of a religious thing. I have always learned the terminology "methods" during my education, and it is my personal preference. From what I have seen, more and more people are starting to use the term "methods."

Answer (score 1):

**function:** 
a generic term for something that accepts input and produce output(data, behaviour). there is also a term function in math.

**method:**
is a function commonly used in object-oriented programming topic. it is a part of an "object" to perform something. maybe there is a history why the word "method" is used. when you have an "object" what do you call to its property to do something? a skill? a talent? action? techniques? behavior? methods? what would be the most appropriate term to use?

**member function:**
is a term commonly used in c/c++ docs/reference/topics/etc. for me this is a more accurate and easier-to-grasp-the-meaning term compared to the word "method". but we are talking about coding here instead of purely object-oriented programming.

***in summary:***
**method** == **member function** and they are both **function**.

for the **method member**... where did you get that  term?! ;))
 i guess it seems the same with method and member function.

Answer (score 0):

Method is just language agnostic name for a routine / operation / thingy in a class that isn't data.

Function and procedure et al, being language constructs introduced a lot of baggage that were obscuring the basic principal.