# What exactly is a class and an object in java, please explain in detail

Tags: java, class, object

I'm a beginner in java, and I've gone through various definitions of OOP concepts, but I've never really understood the concept of a class and object, so could someone please explain this to me. and please don't just say an object is an instance of a class , what exactly does that mean? examples would help

Comment: What tutorials have you read that didn't explain well enough?

Comment: class is how you define a "human" in an abstract manner, objects are the humans you see in the street. now think how a human exists (class design) and then open your window and see your objects =)

Comment: In simple terms a class describes/defines the methods and properties of an object.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28computer_programming%29

Comment: BTW, I can understand people's confusion on this issue. Traditional descriptions of objects as "things" strive to describe what is really a very simple concept in abstract terms. But even here, it is incorrect to say that an object is a "thing" in the same way an idea or a thought might be described as things. Objects are not things, they are abstract representations of things and herein lies the source of most confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most OOP languages, an "object" is a data-structure upon which you can perform a fixed set of actions or operations and a "class" is the means used to define what data an object contains (or has access to) and what operations it can perform or can be performed upon it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay first off I'd recommend reading [The Java (tm) Tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/), wouldn't hurt watching videos on [Udacity](http://www.udacity.com/overview/Course/cs262/CourseRev/apr2012) too.

```
public class Student {
    private int id;
    private String major;
    private Integer age;
    public Student(int id, String major, Integer age){
        this.id = id;
        this.major = major;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    public String getMajor() {
        return this.major;
    }
    public Integer getAge(){
        return this.age;
    }
    . . .
}
```

So an object in this instance is the data type `Integer` and the primitive object is `int`. Each of `id`, `major`, `age` are instance variables of `Student`. Constructors are used to create objects, each time you initiate a constructor you are creating a new instance (every instance is different from the last).

Comment: Hi Killrawr, thanks for your answer. I also had another question regarding the this. method, what is it used for? My teacher in class used this once, but I never understood its purpose, could you please explain this to me, thanks!

Comment: Check my answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513654/function-or-method-or-function-member-or-method-member/11513708#11513708

Answer (score 0):

**Object**

- An object is a thing, both tangible and intangible, that we can
  imagine.

**Class**

- A class is a template definition that dictates what objects can and
  cannot do
- A class is a prototype from which objects are created

Answer (score 0):

A Class is a definition of some *thing*. An Object is one of those *things*.

One of the most common examples is a car. Say you have a class `Car`. That class defines everything about the car. Size, color, make, model, and other things that describe a car are called properties.

A car can also do things, like move, accelerate, turn, reverse, shift. These are called methods. They are what the car can do (some languages call these "actions", which I think is a better term).

When you combine properties and methods into a group, you would call that a [class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28computer_programming%29), because together they define a car (or whatever you are defining).

An object is an instance of a car. That is the simplest way to put it. But what is an instance? [According to wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_%28computer_science%29):

> In object-oriented programming an instance is an occurrence or a copy of an [object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_%28computer_science%29).

That probably seems cyclical, calling an instance an object and vice versa. But technically, an object is a location in memory having a value that can be referenced elsewhere. To make things simpler, we combine the two to mean the same thing. *An instance is an object, an object is an instance*.

### Make it Short

Perhaps the shortest way I can put it is like this:

> A class is a definition, and an object is something that fits that definition.

### Applications in Java

Since you tagged your question with Java, I will continue my example in Java. Let's go back to the car.

The code for what we described above could look something like this:

```
class Car {
  /* Properties */
  int size;
  Color c;
  String make;
  String model;

  /* Constructor */
  Car() {
    // constructor code...
  }

  /* Methods */
  void move() { }
  void accelerate() { }
  void turn() { }
  void reverse() { }
  void shift() { }
}
```

I've labeled each group of things here. We have the properties at the top; the things *describe* a car. And we have the methods at the bottom; the things that a car can *do*.

But in the middle I put something else. It is something that is required to have in almost every class: the *constructor*. What a constructor does is it instantiates a class into an object.

Using the definitions I made above, we can rewrite that last sentence like this:

> A constructor puts an occurrence of a class into a location in memory.

Hopefully this helps you understand classes a little better.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jon, that was perfect! I really loved how you used an example to illustrate your point, it really drove the point home because I seem to understand a lot better with examples.

Answer (score 0):

A class can be seen as a definition of an object; the idea of what makes up a type of object.  The object is an example of that class.

Take a (real-world, not the OS) window, such as the one I'm looking out right now.  "Window" is a *class* - it has a defined operation (open()), and properties (height and width).  This *particular* window I'm looking out of (this *instance* of a Window; this object of the Window class) can be opened by turning a crank, and it is ~60 inches high and 30 inches wide.  In java:

```
class Window {
  int width;
  int height;

  void open() {
  }
}

Window myWindow = new Window();  //instance of the class
myWindow.width = 30;
myWindow.height = 60; 
myWindow.open();
```

Comment: so in the constructor(Window myWindow = new Window();), MyWindow an instance of the class, or an object?

Comment: As you said yourself, an object **is an** instance of a class. There's no "or" in there.

Comment: but the object itself is myWindow and the class is Window, is that interpretation correct?